# Intellisense with Union Types

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I find that intellisense is missing when assigning to a var with a type that is a union type. This makes sense - the compiler doesn't know which of the unioned types you are assigning (although at some point it could deduce when it has enough information but it does not do this either...).

Fine - so I can be explicit and cast the assignment to the type I intend, and the intellisense returns. But this leads to a second problem - for some reason it seems that TypeScript will allow the cast of an empty object literal to any interface, but as soon as a single property is added, the object literal must satisfy the entire interface.

If have two direct questions about this behavior, and they are in the comments in the following code example. I realize I could declare the test vars of more specific types - that is not the point of this topic. Thanks for your help.

```
interface ITestOne {
    a: string;
    b?: string;
}

interface ITestTwo {
    c: string;
}

type EitherType = ITestOne | ITestTwo;

var test1: EitherType = {}; // ERROR, no intellisense to help fill out the required properties in the object literal
var test2: EitherType = {} as ITestOne; // ALLOWED - Why is this allowed?
var test3: EitherType = { b: 'blah' } as ITestOne; // ERROR: property a is missing. Why ISN'T this allowed if the line above is allowed?
```

#### UPDATE 2017-0131

Reply From a bug report I opened on the typescript project on this topic:

What type assertion does, it tells the compiler to "shut up" and trust you. The operator behaves both as an upcast and as a downcast operator. The only check is that the one of the types is assignable to the other.

In the example above, for test: {a: string, b?:string} is assignable to {} (which requires no arguments); for test2 {a: string, b?:string} is assignable to {b:string}, since the type of the only required argument in the target b matches. for test3 neither {a: string, b?:string} is assignable to {b:string, x:string} since it is missing x nor {b:string, x:string} to {a: string, b?:string} since it is missing a.

So, when casting, the source or the target are only verified not to be two completely unrelated types (i.e. number and string), but otherwise the assignment is allowed. My test3 case produced the described result in TypeScript 1.7, but it is now allowed in TypeScript 2.1.

My question about how to get meaningful intellisense in this scenario still stands. However, I suspect the answer is that it is simply not supported without the use of a type guard block.

Comment: test3 works okay for me in the playground. Other than that, you may have discovered a bug... `var test4: ITestTwo = {} as ITestTwo;` ...compiler doesn't complain about that either.

Comment: I think test2 works for some compatibility. Often if you want to use library where you know that something exists but no definition is for it and you don't want to create definition for that (for example insufficient time). You can force language service to work with this as `any` for example and suppress the error message. For example `{}.foo = "bar"` is invalid but after typing to any: `({} as any).foo = "bar"`or `(<any>{}).foo = "bar"`. In old ages when TS don't support assigning type for this in callbacks I used `(<MaClass>this)` and intelisense begin to work.